# how to read a file "mydata.bin" into R

Tags: r, python-2.7

I have a few files with .bin extension such as `mydata1.bin`, `mydata2.bin`, etc. I want to read these files into R so that I can structure them into a data frame.

Files contains the following data:

```
"2016-07-22`353032173`kataraqatar`Katara was born out of a long held vision to position Qatar as an international cultural lighthouse. We will be sharing Katara's latest news and updates.`15`224247`1`280`Doha, Qatar`Kuwait`16485`2016-07-21  17:01:13`4`756172188416413696`NULL`NULL`und`False`2`لكي تكون قريب من فعاليات وأنشطة #كتارا اتصل على 182Be close to the #Katara events and activities, by calling: 182 url`NULL`NULL`url
2016-07-22`353032173`kataraqatar`Katara was born out of a long held vision to position Qatar as an international cultural lighthouse. We will be sharing Katara's latest news and updates.`15`224247`1`280`Doha, Qatar`Kuwait`16485`2016-07-21  15:00:59`14`756141931495915520`NULL`NULL`ar`False`1`يُلقي خطبة الجمعة فضيلة الشيخ محمد مكي، إمام وخطيب جامع #كتارابعنوان "الثقة بالله في الأزمات"#كتارا_ملتقى_الثقافات url`NULL`NULL`url
2016-07-22`353032173`kataraqatar`Katara was born ..... "
```

The separator is: `` ` ``.

Comment: File extension is  :-    .bin             Separator is :-      "`"

Comment: did you try `?readBin`

Comment: yes... but I did not work. May be I don`t know how to use it aptly. but I read a document and followed the steps.

Comment: try this if it helps you df <- read.delim("path to your /df.bin", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something along this line ?

```
setwd("/path/to/your/files")
files <- c("mydata1.bin","mydata2.bin")
list_of_df <- lapply(files,read.delim,sep="`",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=FALSE)
final_df <- do.call(rbind,list_of_df)
```

Create a vector of your files, loop over this list to create a list of dataframes by reading the `` ` `` separated entries.

Then row bind each dataframe of the list into a final dataframe.